# Regex to retrieve a string between square brackets and specific string

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a RegEx in c# to retrieve a string which is between square brackets and a specific string. For example, for the following cases

1. `Sum(Num[FriendlyName1]) + [FriendlyName2]` should give back just `FriendlyName1`
2. `Count([FriendlyName1])/[FriendlyName2]` should give back just `FriendlyName1`.
3. `[FriendlyName1] + [FriendlyName2]` should give back no matches

What I have come up is the RegEx `(?<=(?i)sum\(|count\()(.*?)(?=\])`. 
The above RegEx gives me:
1. `Num[FriendlyName1`
2. `Num[FriendlyName1`
3. no match
for the above cases. I can use the `SubString` method then to get the string after the index of char `[`. But I'd like to know if I can achieve this using just the RegEx. The thing which is missing is taking care of any string that comes between `Sum(` or `Count(` and before the `[`. 
My example can be accessed [here](https://regex101.com/r/RZaanE/1).

Comment: I don't think you can do this in just one pass of the regex, since lookbehinds must be fixed width and you currently want to match one with unknown width (the `Num`). But you can do two hopefully?

Comment: @CalumYou: no, lookbehinds don't have this limitation with .net. (nor with pcre if you use an alternation with fixed length branches).

Comment: [`(?<=(?i:sum\(|count\()[^\[]*\[)(.*?)(?=\])`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%28%3fi%3asum%5c%28%7ccount%5c%28%29%5b%5e%5c%5b%5d*%5c%5b%29%28.*%3f%29%28%3f%3d%5c%5d%29&i=Sum%28Num%5bFriendlyName1%5d%29+%2b+%5bFriendlyName2%5d+should+give+back+just+%5bFriendlyName1%5d%0d%0aCount%28%5bFriendlyName1%5d%29%2f%5bFriendlyName2%5d+should+give+back+just+%5bFriendlyName1%5d.%0d%0a%5bFriendlyName1%5d+%2b+%5bFriendlyName2%5d+sho) should work.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte your regex works fine in that link for the test case `Sum (Num ([StoryPointsGroomed])) < 50` but fails in VS 2017 .NET 4.7

Answer (score 0):

What about this using this :

```
(?<=(Sum|Count)[^[]+\[)[^]]+
```

[test](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3C%3d%28Sum%7cCount%29%5b%5e%5b%5d%2b%5c%5b%29%5b%5e%5d%5d%2b&i=Sum%28Num%5bFriendlyName1%5d%29+%2b+%5bFriendlyName2%5d+should+give+back+just+%5bFriendlyName1%5d%0d%0aCount%28%5bFriendlyName1%5d%29%2f%5bFriendlyName2%5d+should+give+back+just+%5bFriendlyName1%5d.%0d%0a%5bFriendlyName1%5d+%2b+%5bFriendlyName2%5d+should+give+back+no+matches%0d%0a)

```
Sum(Num[FriendlyName1]) + [FriendlyName2] give back FriendlyName1
Count([FriendlyName1])/[FriendlyName2]  give back FriendlyName1
[FriendlyName1] + [FriendlyName2]  no matches
```

Comment: your regex works fine in that link for the test case `Sum (Num ([StoryPointsGroomed])) < 50` but fails in VS 2017 .NET 4.7